# Azure Service Bus WCF service starting but not receiving messages

Tags: azureservicebus

I have just written my first WCF service to attach to Azure Service Bus and handle incoming messages. The web.config looks like:

```
   <services>
      <service name="Acme.Services.ClientManagementService.ClientManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <endpoint name="ClientManagementService" address="sb://acme.servicebus.windows.net/ClientManagement.GetAllClients" binding="netMessagingBinding" contract="Acme.Services.ClientManagementService.IClientManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="securityBehavior"/>
      </service>
   </services>
```

When I run the service in the debugger, it starts up without complaining. The problem is no matter how many messages I post to the ClientManagement.GetAllClients topic, none appear to ever be delivered to the service.

Any pointers on how to fix/debug this?

Comment: are you hosting the service in IIS ?  in that case, you'll need autostart to be configured.

Comment: I have now configured autostart on the app pool and the application but I am still not seeing messages hitting the service. Is there anyway I can if the service is attached to the service bus?

Comment: you don't see any warnings/messages in the system or application event log?  normally when things fail, there you can see the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Topic/Subscriptions with the WCF publish/subscribe service model, for adding the service endpoint you must specify the topic URI (namespace/topicname) as the address, and the subscription URI (namespace/topicname/Subscriptions/subname) as the listening URI.

There are some samples that cover this scenario so may also want to cross check:
1) http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/WCF-with-Service-Bus-d3987eaf
2) http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Service-Bus-netMessagingBin-9ae8ad13
3) http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-WCF-ed259f73