# Console hosted WCF not talking to Azure SeviceBus

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, azureservicebus

I have the following console application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;

    Console.WriteLine("**** Client Management Service ****");

    string serviceNamespace = "abcdef";
    string issuerName = "owner";
    string issuerSecret = "abcdef...";

    // Create the credentials object for the endpoint.
    TransportClientEndpointBehavior sharedSecretServiceBusCredential = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior();
    sharedSecretServiceBusCredential.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerSecret);

    // Create the service URI based on the service namespace.
    Uri address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", serviceNamespace, "management.getallclients");

    //// Create the ServiceRegistrySettings behavior for the endpoint.
    IEndpointBehavior serviceRegistrySettings = new ServiceRegistrySettings(DiscoveryType.Public);

    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ManagementService), address);

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IManagementService), new NetMessagingBinding(), address);

    // Add the Service Bus credentials to all endpoints specified in configuration.
    foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
    {
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(serviceRegistrySettings);
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(sharedSecretServiceBusCredential);
    }

    // Open the service.
    host.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();

    host.Close();
}
```

The service definition is

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "IManagementService")]
public interface IManagementService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void GetAllClients(string correlationId);
}
```

This opens the host quite nicely and sits there, but no messages sent to the service bus topic "management.getallclients" ever reach it.

Using Service Bus Explorer, I am not convinced that the host is actually attaching to service bus as the "Last Accessed" timestamp does not change when I run the console application.

Any ideas why I am not seeing messages?

Answer (score 1):

Colin,
Is this still an issue or was related to: [Azure Service Bus WCF service starting but not receiving messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110416/azure-service-bus-wcf-service-starting-but-not-receiving-messages/23138637#23138637)

Regards,

-Abhishek.